# What is the Criteria of Technology Readiness Level 9?

Tags: launch, electronics, specifications

On [NASA website](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/engineering/technology/technology_readiness_level) it says to get TRL 9 the technology must be flight proven, now, to be "flight proven" is there any specific criteria for that? like a defined amount of time of functioning, radiation, altitude, etc.?
Or is it once the technology (let's say a PCB) is in space then that is it, it is certified as space-qualified?

Comment: In addition to passing the specific requirements for TRL 9 to attain TRL 9, the technology in question has to pass the requirements for technology readiness levels one to eight.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You seek Appendix E of ***NASA Systems Engineering Processes and Requirements (NPR 7123.1C)*** which defines the technology readiness levels.

You can find the official definitions [here](https://nodis3.gsfc.nasa.gov/displayDir.cfm?Internal_ID=N_PR_7123_001C_&page_name=AppendixE). *Effective Date: February 14, 2020*

tl;dr It had to have flown in space and worked right

| TRL | Definition | Hardware Description | Software Description | Exit Criteria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | Actual system flight proven through successful mission operations. | The final product is successfully operated in an actual mission. | All software has been thoroughly debugged and fully integrated with all operational hardware and software systems. All documentation has been completed. Sustaining software support is in place. System has been successfully operated in the operational environment. | Documented mission operational results. |

Comment: interesting that "Verification and Validation completed" was added to Software.  All the rest of that is pretty sad.  I wonder who was upset enough that things aren't TRL 9 the first time you operate them to put those changes through.

Comment: @ErinAnne see comment and proposed edit - the claim isn't true.

Comment: @Brondahl thanks! I misread the new chart. Apologies to all.

Comment: @OrganicMarble  no worries :)

Comment: @ErinAnne see answer as corrected by Brondahl. I made a dumb mistake.

Comment: I'm amazed that they don't mention any amount of time! We know how harsh the space is, so I assumed a minimum period of time is a must to be certified, say a month or a even a week!!

Comment: @MohamedAbduljawad there is definitely a lot of wiggle room in the criteria. "Successfully operated" could mean a lot of things.

Comment: @MohamedAbduljawad: I assume it's so vague because it's meant to be general and not assume a specific application. Something that's TRL 9 for a satellite in LEO may not be TRL 9 for, say, a Venus lander. Heck, the definitions don't even assume that the relevant application is in space. The coffee maker in the mission control break room is probably TRL 9 for its operational environment, but you wouldn't want to send it to space.

Comment: my fault for thinking Marble was TRL 9

Comment: Re *Now, it doesn't actually have to fly to be flight proven*: The concept of technology readiness level has turned out to be so useful that it now applies to much more than flight hardware, which was the original target. Flight software was an add-on, and non-flight hardware / software were even later add-ons. How do you qualify non-flight hardware as TRL 9 if only flight-tested hardware can qualify as TRL 9? The answer is simple: Expand what it means to qualify as TRL 9. Flight hardware still needs to be flown to qualify as TRL 9.

Comment: @MohamedAbduljawad: That would mean that almost no first stage system would ever become TRL9, since they only ever operate for 2–5 minutes and then get destroyed*. Requiring something which only operates for 2–5 minutes total (and only spends half of that time in space) to be tested in space for a *month* would be totally ridiculous. You would need to add literally tons of useless and extremely expensive radiation shielding, tank insulation, batteries, solar panels, heating elements, radiators, etc. for the sole purpose of passing TRL9, and then never, ever use that stuff again operationally.

Comment: [* Falcon 9, Space Shuttle SRBs, Electron, and New Shepard excluded.]